# Recover default style when modified with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

In a JS function, I've set the background color of a text field like this:

```
document.getElementsByName(formId)[0].title.style.backgroundColor = "#7FB75E";
```

In another function, I want to reset the background color to the default value defined in my style sheet. How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just set the value on the "style" object to the empty string.

```
document.getElementsByName(formId)[0].title.style.backgroundColor = "";
```

*edit* — note that if your element had an inline style, you'd have to explicitly save that somewhere or else you won't be able to get it back.

Comment: This answer is better than mine.

Comment: @jessegavin well your answer is correct too - if the element is styled with inline CSS then it would have to be saved.

Comment: But this removes any style - not restore it

Comment: @Fernando68 true - I'll add a little detail to the answer (6 years old!) (Actually I think that's what I meant; the value of the *property* on the "style" object. It was not clear however.)

Answer (score 4):

Before setting the background color to the new value, store it as a property on that element for later retrieval like so.

```
var el = document.getElementsByName(formId)[0].title;
el._originalBackgroundColor = el.style.backgroundColor;


// Set the new color
el.style.backgroundColor = "#7FB75E";

// Set it back to original
el.style.backgroundColor = el._originalBackgroundColor;
```

Comment: Thanks, I now took Pointy's answer for my code, but this solution here seems to work too.

Comment: You should make sure to click the checkmark to the left of his answer then. It let's future readers know that it's the answer you chose.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered, but the OP asked how to restore the style that was changed via Javascript. In otherwords, how do I restore the style my element had BEFORE it was changed by something else. I am sorry, but I don't think the answers above do this. The answers **remove** the style, not restore 
it!

I use CSS as much as I can and I've managed a way to "layer" a new CSS style onto an element and remove the layer as required, revealing the original/default style.

Lets' assume I have a gridview with the following css...

```
table.gvCSS {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font: 12px Verdana;
}

table.gvCSS > tbody > tr {
  background-color: white;
}

table.gvCSS > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #EEE;
}

table.gvCSS > tbody > tr:first-of-type {
  background-color: #5D7B9D;
  color: white;
}

table.gvCSS > tbody > tr.selected-row {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

My GridView ...

```
            <asp:GridView ID="gvTETstudents" runat="server" 
                CssClass="gvCSS">
               <Columns>
....
...
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Orange" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

These little functions control adding and removing the classes as I need them...

```
function hasClass(ele,cls) {
  return !!ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
}

function addClass(ele,cls) {
  if (!hasClass(ele,cls)) ele.className += " "+cls;
}

function removeClass(ele,cls) {
  if (hasClass(ele,cls)) {
    var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
    ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
  }
}

function highlightRow(chk) {
  var row = chk.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  if (chk.checked)
    addClass(row, 'selected-row');
  else
    removeClass(row, 'selected-row');
}
```

So when ever I need to toggle the row background for example ...

```
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSKIP" runat="server" 
                            Font-Size="10pt" Font-Italic="true" ForeColor="DarkGreen" BackColor="Yellow"
                            onClick="highlightRow(this)"
                            ToolTip="Choosing this will save the comment into the student's contact-log, but not actually email it!"
                            Text="SAVE TO CONTACT-LOG ONLY (no email)?" />
```

No matter what styles you had in the original row, the above will apply a new style and remove it, revealing what you had originally (ie: the toggle of the gridview's rows in an alternate fashion).